# zsh: no matches found when using mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I used mongo dump to store all the data into a file called my_config in desktop, but when I wang to restore into another db, I got this error, can anyone help me with this?

```
zsh: no matches found: mongodb://tax-engine-config_appuser:mypassword@myport:27017/tax-engine-config?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Here is the command I'm using

```
mongorestore mongodb://'tax-engine-config_appuser:mypassword'@myport:27017/tax-engine-config?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1 my_config/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `?`in your connection URI.

1. You'll either have to put the entire URI in quotes

```bash
"mongorestore mongodb://'tax-engine-config_appuser:mypassword'@myport:27017/tax-engine-config?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1 my_config/
"
```

or

2. Escape it with a backlash